# Why does Object Browser not find ole32 functions?

Tags: objectbrowser

This may be a dumb question - so be it, I'm a newb. But I'm trying to implement a code snippet

```
pszReturn = (char*)::CoTaskMemAlloc(ulSize);
```

And when I try to type in the function CoTaskMemAlloc, Intellisense does not find it. Now I looked it up, and I believe it resides in ole32.dll (I'm "developing" on a virtual WinServer 64bit Visual Studio 2012).

Why is ole32 not loading? Is it related to the fact that my project is not registered for COM?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to include the header file for it (objbase.h)! All is well now....